# Building a fast distributed web crawler

Tags: web-crawler, message-queue, distributed-computing

I have built a distributed web crawler with a workpool architecture in Python, using RabbitMQ.

Workpools are known for having a bottleneck at the master node, but in this case there is no problem because some computation is needed at each slave node after scrapping every webpage. The master node has also to be able to coordinate multiple 'crawls' so it launches one thread per query.

My main problem with the solution described above is that the thread handling and distributed communication in python is **really** slow. Therefore, I am willing to change the programming language in other to have a more efficient crawling. I ask you, stackoverflowers, in which language should I build my crawler? Please remember the specification that I mentioned in the second paragraph.

Ask me anything that you did not understand. Thanks!

Comment: Assembly is by far the fastest. In all seriousness though, you should first measure what's actually slow and why.

Comment: @kichik not Assembly! ahah but not Python either for distributed/parallel stuff ^^''

Comment: If by "computation" you mean "cpu bound task" then as always C++ (or even C) would be a good choice. These can even be married with Python (as [C/C++ extensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html)).

Comment: @freakish I want something relatively fast and easy to implement this. I have used OpenMP and MPI in C++ and they could deal with the parallel/distributed part (respectively) and call python scripts to do the scrapping. However I would like something more high level where implementing message queues is not that complicated

Comment: @RedRose Well, it's a very long fight between performance and ease of programming (and maintaining). So far it's hard (if possible) to have both.

Comment: On the other hand if few machines can solve your problem then I wouldn't bother with switching to other language.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming in python? Ask in: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @freakish thanks for your opinion :)
Still hoping that someone points me out an easy-fast solution to implement message queues and threads. maybe Go?

Comment: You should try nodejs, which has event IO